# Pass dataframe cells as variables

Tags: python, pandas, eval

I have the folowing input CSV file:

```
prefix_files = 'wave6results_'

op2file= 'TRAM.op2'

fmin= 11
fmax= 20
df= 3.0

bemsurface= ['PCOMP PID_260002', 'PCOMP PID_260003', 'PCOMP PID_260004', 'PCOMP PID_260005', 'PCOMP PID_260006', 'PCOMP PID_260016', 'PCOMP PID_260026']

meshsize= 0.07  
areathreshold= 0.02

dafspectra= [134.7, 138.2, 142.0, 140.6, 135.1, 129.0, 124.5, 120.7, 117.7, 0]

dlf= [0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02]

output_acc= 1    
name_acc= ['Capteurs Coque', 'Capteurs Backing Structure']
    
ranges_acc= [[100000, 100999],[600000, 600999]]

output_force=  1
name_force= ['SPC set10']

output_cons= 1

name_cons= 'FePID'

FePID_cons= [260002, 260003, 260004, 260005, 260006, 260016, 260026, 460006, 464800, 464801, 466200, 470006, 474800, 474801, 476200, 480000, 480001, 480200, 480240, 490300, 496301, 527001, 527002, 600300, 610000, 620200, 620350, 620550, 630200, 700800, 800000, 800001, 820000, 821000]
```

As you can guess, I want to pass them into my Python script such that, for example, the variable bemsurface is a list composed of all the 'PCOMP PID...' you see in the first line of my CSV extract.

I believe the easiest way to get those variables is going through pandas, so I coded something like:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
path_csv = Path('CreateModel_input_test.csv')

input_values = pd.read_csv(path_csv, names = ['variables','values'], delimiter='=')
```

This gives me a nice dataframe with, on one column the names of the variables I want and on the other column their values.

```
    1                2
0   prefix_files     'wave6results_'
1   op2file          'TRAM.op2'
2   fmin             11
3   fmax             20
4   df               3.0
5   bemsurface       ["PCOMP PID_260002", "PCOMP PID_260003", "PCOMP PID_260004", "PCOMP PID_260005", "PCOMP PID_260006", "PCOMP PID_260016", "PCOMP PID_260026"]
6   meshsize         0.07
```

Now I know the eval() function is to be avoided at all cost, so how would you go through the dataframe and assign the values on the right to variables named from the left column?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Can you provide a pruned example of the CSV file? I think using pandas here might be overcomplicating things as from what I understand you don't need the df. I think a JSON might be better suited for the datastructure you want...

Comment: What do you mean by pruned example?

Comment: just a couple of rows of data, not 1,000,000 rows of data

Comment: Ah sure, I'll edit the post now, thanks for your help
The csv file is quite small anyhow

Comment: just as an FYI, that is *not* a CSV file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `globals()` and `ast.literal_eval()` if you want to use pandas and this kind of configuration file:

```py
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"0": ["test_var"], "1": ["['a', 'b', 'c', 545.5]"]})

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    globals()[row[0]] = literal_eval(row[1])
    
print(test_var)
```

**However**, it is neither an efficient nor a safe solution (what if one variable is named like a builtin?). I'd recommend to a more robust approach via using the json format:

**config.json**

```json
{
 'prefix_files': 'wave6results',
 'bemsurface': ['PCOMP PID_260002', 'PCOMP PID_260003', 'PCOMP PID_260004', 'PCOMP PID_260005', 'PCOMP PID_260006', 'PCOMP PID_260016', 'PCOMP PID_260026']
}
```

**script.py**

```py
import json

with open("config.json") as file:
   config = json.load(file)

# Access
print(config['bemsurface'])
```

It is much safer and more standard this way.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would keep them in a dictionary.

`input_values.to_dict()`

And then reference from there.

You could try adding them to local environment like so `locals().update(input_values)` but I wouldn't encourage it.